# SUM c условием из 2х таблиц

Tags: android, sqlite

Есть таблица со счетами и начальным балансом bills, есть таблица с операциями transactions.
transactions_type - тип операции, 1 - расход, 2 - доход.

Надо вывести id всех счетов и остаток по ним, учитывая начальный баланс bill_start.

```
CREATE TABLE transactions (
_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
bill_id INTEGER,
transaction_type INTEGER, 
transaction_summ REAL
);

CREATE TABLE bills (
_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
bill_name TEXT,
bill_start REAL
);

INSERT INTO transactions (bill_id,transaction_type,transaction_summ)
VALUES (1, 1, 90);
INSERT INTO transactions (bill_id,transaction_type,transaction_summ)
VALUES (1, 2, 50);
INSERT INTO transactions (bill_id,transaction_type,transaction_summ)
VALUES (2, 2, 10);

INSERT INTO bills (bill_name, bill_start)
VALUES ('Счет 1', 50);
INSERT INTO bills (bill_name, bill_start)
VALUES ('Счет 2', 20);
INSERT INTO bills (bill_name, bill_start)
VALUES ('Счет 3', 1);
```

Додумал до такого:

```
 SELECT transactions.bill_id,
bills.bill_start + SUM( case when transactions.transaction_type=1 then -transactions.transaction_summ else transactions.transaction_summ end )  AS sum
FROM transactions join bills on transactions.bill_id = bills._id GROUP BY bill_id;
```

Но такой запрос не выводит счет №3 c балансом 1, так как по нему нет операций.
Как поправить?

UPD Если поменять местами таблицы, и использовать LEFT JOIN не получилось

```
SELECT transactions.bill_id,
bills.bill_start + SUM( case when transactions.transaction_type=1 then -transactions.transaction_summ else transactions.transaction_summ end )  AS sum
FROM bills LEFT JOIN transactions on bills._id = transactions.bill_id GROUP BY bill_id;

| bill_id |    sum |
|---------|--------|
|  (null) | (null) |
|       1 |     10 |
|       2 |     30 |
```

Comment: используйте `right join` вместо просто `join`. или left, в зависимости от того в какой из таблиц у вас может не быть данных

Comment: На right join sqlite ругается: "RIGHT and FULL OUTER JOINs are not currently supported"

Comment: Переставьте таблицы местами и используйте left. В интернете по sqllight lft join куча примеров, значит он должен это поддерживать

Comment: Right не работает, в документации SQLite сказано "TIP: The RIGHT OUTER JOIN and FULL OUTER JOIN are not supported in SQLite." Если поменять таблицы местами получаю в выдаче еще одну строку c bill_id = null  sum=null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помог совет поменять местами таблицы. Возник подводный камень в SUM - во второй таблице не было записей связаных с одним элементом первой таблицы (bills._id = 3), поэтому SUM возвращал null, проблема была решена с помощью IFNULL

```
SELECT bills.bill_name,
bills.bill_start + ifnull(SUM( case when transactions.transaction_type=1 then -transactions.transaction_summ else transactions.transaction_summ end ), 0)  AS sum
FROM bills left join transactions on bills._id = transactions.bill_id GROUP BY bill_id;
```